# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in java library from Kotlin on Android 5

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, java-8

Подтягиваю внешнюю **JAVA**-зависимость из репозитория из **android**-приложения на **Kotlin**, в итоге получаю падение на **android 5** по ***java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method*** по трейсу внутри **JAVA**-библиотеки (трейс приложен внизу). Причём ругался на отсутствие класса **Stream** из библиотеки retro stream. Проверил, во внешних зависимостях эта зависимость есть и видна из кода, причём, что самое интересное - не падает на android **>=7** устройствах.

Для сборки используется **gradle** + **kotlin DSL** (на **groovy DSL** - всё тоже самое). Среда - **Android studio**.

```
Версии:
Kotlin         1.3.50
Gradle plugin  3.4.2
Gradle         5.4.1    
Android studio 3.5
```

Строка, вызывающая падение:

```java
EmptyUtils.getLastNotNullGotValue(Supplier { "" })
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): Process: com.jetruby.kotlindslgradleexample, PID: 5699 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava9/util/stream/Stream; or its super classes (declaration of 'java9.util.stream.Stream' appears in /data/app/com.jetruby.kotlindslgradleexample-2/base.apk) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at ru.m4bank.mpos.service.network.utils.EmptyUtils.getLastNotNullGotValueOrDefault(EmptyUtils.java:40) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at ru.m4bank.mpos.service.network.utils.EmptyUtils.getLastNotNullGotValue(EmptyUtils.java:51) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at com.jetruby.kotlindslgradleexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5699):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Поэкспериментировав с различными вариантами сборок обнаружил, что если подтягивать **JAVA**-зависимость локально (файлом) - падения не происходит и на **5-м** **android!!**. Также падения не происходит, если собирать из **JAVA**, а не из **kotlin**. Причём падает только на статических методах в интерфейсах.

На картинке ниже 2 одинаковых зависимости (1-ю я скопировал из кэша **gradle**, когда подтягивал 2-ю и подтянул локально файлом, 2-ю просто стянул из репозитория).

```
На **android <7** с первой не падает, со второй - падает.
На **android >=7** - не падает с обеими
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Декомпилировав приложение, заметил, что из kotlin статические методы из интерфейсов собираются в отдельный класс (создаётся вспомагательный inner-класс **ClassName.CC** и в него помещаются статические методы). Так вот при подтягивании зависимости из репозитория декомпилированный внешний класс обращается к оригинальному классу и оригинальному методу, а при подтягивании из локального источника (скопировал из подтянутого репозитория в папку **libs**) - обращается к вспомогательному **XX.CC**. Есть подозрение, что именно поэтому и вылетает ***java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method***.

[image: Классы, созданные для Stream при подтягивании из репозитория (падение)]

Ниже декомпилированный код "вспомогательного" класса с "отсутствующим" методом ***of***. Он одинаковый, как для удачной, так и для не удачной сборки:

```java
    .class public final synthetic Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$-CC;
    .super Ljava/lang/Object;
    .source "Stream.java"
    
    
    # direct methods
    .method public static $default$dropWhile(Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 3
        .param p0, "_this"    # Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "(",
                "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<",
                "-TT;>;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 630
        .local p0, "this":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<TT;>;"
        .local p1, "predicate":Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;, "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<-TT;>;"
        invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 633
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Dropping;
    
        .line 634
        invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        const/4 v2, 0x1
    
        invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Dropping;-><init>(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;ZLjava9/util/function/Predicate;)V
    
        .line 635
        invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z
    
        move-result v1
    
        .line 633
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        .line 635
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->closeHandler(Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->onClose(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        check-cast v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static $default$takeWhile(Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 3
        .param p0, "_this"    # Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "(",
                "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<",
                "-TT;>;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 564
        .local p0, "this":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<TT;>;"
        .local p1, "predicate":Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;, "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<-TT;>;"
        invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 567
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Taking;
    
        .line 568
        invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        const/4 v2, 0x1
    
        invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Taking;-><init>(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;ZLjava9/util/function/Predicate;)V
    
        .line 569
        invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z
    
        move-result v1
    
        .line 567
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        .line 569
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->closeHandler(Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->onClose(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        check-cast v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static builder()Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$Builder;
        .locals 1
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">()",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$Builder<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1148
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;
    
        invoke-direct {v0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;-><init>()V
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static concat(Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 3
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">(",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "+TT;>;",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "+TT;>;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1387
        .local p0, "a":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<+TT;>;"
        .local p1, "b":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<+TT;>;"
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 1388
        invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 1391
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$ConcatSpliterator$OfRef;
    
        .line 1392
        invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        invoke-interface {p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;
    
        move-result-object v2
    
        invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$ConcatSpliterator$OfRef;-><init>(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Ljava9/util/Spliterator;)V
    
        .line 1393
        .local v0, "split":Ljava9/util/Spliterator;, "Ljava9/util/Spliterator<TT;>;"
        invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z
    
        move-result v1
    
        if-nez v1, :cond_1
    
        invoke-interface {p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z
    
        move-result v1
    
        if-eqz v1, :cond_0
    
        goto :goto_0
    
        :cond_0
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        goto :goto_1
    
        :cond_1
        :goto_0
        const/4 v1, 0x1
    
        :goto_1
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        .line 1394
        .local v1, "stream":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<TT;>;"
        invoke-static {p0, p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams;->composedClose(Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
    
        move-result-object v2
    
        invoke-interface {v1, v2}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->onClose(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;
    
        move-result-object v2
    
        check-cast v2, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        return-object v2
    .end method
    
    .method public static empty()Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 2
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">()",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1158
        invoke-static {}, Ljava9/util/Spliterators;->emptySpliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static generate(Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 3
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">(",
                "Ljava9/util/function/Supplier<",
                "+TT;>;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1345
        .local p0, "s":Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;, "Ljava9/util/function/Supplier<+TT;>;"
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 1346
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSpliterators$InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator$OfRef;
    
        const-wide v1, 0x7fffffffffffffffL
    
        invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSpliterators$InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator$OfRef;-><init>(JLjava9/util/function/Supplier;)V
    
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static iterate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 8
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                "S:TT;>(TS;",
                "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<",
                "TS;>;",
                "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<",
                "TS;>;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1287
        .local p0, "seed":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TS;"
        .local p1, "hasNext":Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;, "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<TS;>;"
        .local p2, "next":Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;, "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<TS;>;"
        invoke-static {p2}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 1288
        invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 1289
        new-instance v7, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$2;
    
        const-wide v1, 0x7fffffffffffffffL
    
        const/16 v3, 0x410
    
        move-object v0, v7
    
        move-object v4, p2
    
        move-object v5, p0
    
        move-object v6, p1
    
        invoke-direct/range {v0 .. v6}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$2;-><init>(JILjava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)V
    
        .line 1331
        .local v0, "spliterator":Ljava9/util/Spliterator;, "Ljava9/util/Spliterator<TT;>;"
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        return-object v1
    .end method
    
    .method public static iterate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 7
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                "S:TT;>(TS;",
                "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<",
                "TS;>;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1224
        .local p0, "seed":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TS;"
        .local p1, "f":Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;, "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<TS;>;"
        invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    
        .line 1225
        new-instance v6, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$1;
    
        const-wide v1, 0x7fffffffffffffffL
    
        const/16 v3, 0x410
    
        move-object v0, v6
    
        move-object v4, p1
    
        move-object v5, p0
    
        invoke-direct/range {v0 .. v5}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$1;-><init>(JILjava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    
        .line 1244
        .local v0, "spliterator":Ljava9/util/Spliterator;, "Ljava9/util/Spliterator<TT;>;"
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v1
    
        return-object v1
    .end method
    
    .method public static of(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 2
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">(TT;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1169
        .local p0, "t":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TT;"
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;
    
        invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static varargs of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 1
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">([TT;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1196
        .local p0, "values":[Ljava/lang/Object;, "[TT;"
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/J8Arrays;->stream([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        return-object v0
    .end method
    
    .method public static ofNullable(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
        .locals 2
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">(TT;)",
                "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                "TT;>;"
            }
        .end annotation
    
        .line 1183
        .local p0, "t":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TT;"
        if-nez p0, :cond_0
    
        invoke-static {}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$-CC;->empty()Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        goto :goto_0
    
        :cond_0
        new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;
    
        invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    
        const/4 v1, 0x0
    
        .line 1184
        invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
    
        move-result-object v0
    
        :goto_0
        return-object v0
    .end method
```

Метод из **JAVA**-библиотеки, который вызывает отсутствующий метод для падающей сборки:

```java
.method public static varargs getLastNotNullValue([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    .locals 2
    .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
        value = {
            "<T:",
            "Ljava/lang/Object;",
            ">([TT;)TT;"
        }
    .end annotation

    .annotation runtime Ljava/lang/SafeVarargs;
    .end annotation

    .line 56
    .local p0, "values":[Ljava/lang/Object;, "[TT;"
    invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

    move-result-object v0

    sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;

    invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->filter(Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-interface {v0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->findFirst()Ljava9/util/Optional;

    move-result-object v0

    sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/Optional;->orElseGet(Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0
.end method
```

Тот же метод для не падающей сборки:

```java
.method public static varargs getLastNotNullValue([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    .locals 2
    .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
        value = {
            "<T:",
            "Ljava/lang/Object;",
            ">([TT;)TT;"
        }
    .end annotation

    .annotation runtime Ljava/lang/SafeVarargs;
    .end annotation

    .line 56
    .local p0, "values":[Ljava/lang/Object;, "[TT;"
    invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$-CC;->of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

    move-result-object v0

    sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;

    invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->filter(Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-interface {v0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->findFirst()Ljava9/util/Optional;

    move-result-object v0

    sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/Optional;->orElseGet(Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0
.end method
```

Вопрос: это баг **kotlin**-а или я что-то делаю неправильно, и как тогда воспользоваться библиотеками **JAVA** из репозитория (которые содержат интерфейсы с статическими методами внутри) на android **<7** и при этом не падать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После обновления версии **Android Gradle Plugin** до **4+** снова столкнулся с проблемой.
**После анализа заметил следующее:**

1. Все мои зависимости были артефактами -> у них нет метаданных.
2. Android Studio собирает apk не так, как в консоли (Она добавляет опции для API устройства во время процесса сборки через кнопку run для её ускорения) -> устройства **android 7+** работают только потому, что целевой **API** был **24+** из-за чего не производился desugaring для статических методов в интерфейсах (Так как этого уже не нужно было делать в силу того, что устройства с таким андроидом поддерживают данный функционал).
3. Java версия работала только благодаря другому механизму дешугаринга и кэширования зависимостей (Перестала работать после обновления **Android Gradle Plugin** до **4+**).
4. Насчет локальных зависимостей: Я предполагаю, что этот вариант работал только потому, что **gradle** не кешировал локальные зависимости.

**Решение:**
Я добавил правильные метаданные к зависимостям (**pom.xml** или **.module** файлы), которые явно помечают граф зависимостей бинарных файлов, и теперь **R8** делает дешугаринг правильно, и всё работает как надо.

**P. S.** Также, если в силу каких-то причин не получается добавить метаданные можно подтянуть все зависимости локально.